# Solve the problem of not playing the sound on the iPhone

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with this code. On Android, it works normally, but on iPhone there is no sound at all. I hope to solve the problem,

```
function fq(e, t, o) {
var n = document.createElement("audio");
(n.srcObject = o), (n.muted = t), (n.autoplay = !0), (n.onpause = function() {
    var t = $(n).parent().find(".evant>#showpf i.sounds")[0];
    $(t).text("turn off the sound"), $(t).text("Audio playback");
    e.removeClass('is_speaking');
}), (n.onplay = function() {
    var t = $(n).parent().find(".evant>#showpf i.sounds")[0];
    $(t).text("Audio playback"), $(t).text("turn off the sound");
    e.addClass('is_speaking');
}), n.addEventListener("ended", () => {
    e.removeClass('is_speaking');
});
n.addEventListener("canplay", () => {
    e.addClass('is_speaking');
});
n.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
    n.play();
}), n.play(), $(n).appendTo(e);
```

}

Comment: Check Safari restrictions, there are lot of them. I'va faced smth like that when I tried to use microphone

Comment: This appears to be in-browser [tag:javascript]; can you elaborate as to why you've selected the [tag:node.js] tag?

Answer (score 0):

Do you init the playback after user interaction?

There are some restrictions that limit starting playback before an user interaction occurs.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10999103/3191478

> - Apple does not allow you to call .play on any audio until user
>   interaction
> - Audio events don't fire if Safari is in the background

Android may have different rules on sound playback.

Comment: Yes, audio starts playing after user interaction